# Getting the sum of all radio button values to display in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have some radio buttons in a table and I’ve set a value to them. When the user selects them and clicks the submit button, I want the sum of those values to show in another table.

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <span id="Label1">hows the weather ?</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <table id="a1_1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="a1_1" id="a1_1_0">
            <label for="a1_1_0">perfect</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="a1_1" id="a1_1_1">
            <label for="a1_1_1">good</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="a1_1" id="a1_1_2">
            <label for="a1_1_2">not bad</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="4" name="a1_1" id="a1_1_3">
            <label for="a1_1_3">bad</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="5" name="a1_1" id="a1_1_4">
            <label for="a1_1_4">very bad</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <span id="Label1">hows the weather ?</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <table id="a1_2">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="a1_2" id="a1_1_0">
            <label for="a1_2_0">perfect</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="a1_2" id="a1_1_1">
            <label for="a1_2_1">good</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="a1_2" id="a1_1_2">
            <label for="a1_2_2">not bad</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="4" name="a1_2" id="a1_1_3">
            <label for="a1_2_3">bad</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" value="5" name="a1_1" id="a1_1_4">
            <label for="a1_2_4">very bad</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i wanna use this html for phonegap and i think i cant use php or anything , just js help me

Comment: then go through some tutorials

Comment: or post a job in freelance sites

Comment: Why are you even using tables, let alone nested tables?

Comment: document.getElementById('idofradiobutton').value; will give the corresponding value

Comment: Really easy with ES6: `var sum=[...document.querySelectorAll(':checked')].map(a=>Number(a.value)).reduce((a,b)=>(a+b),0);`.

Comment: @Xufox "Really easy" :) You should try that an an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of an element, you can set an id to the element, then reference the element by id.
ex.

```
<script>
    function sumRadioInputs() {
        var valueOfInput = document.getElementById("someElementId").value;
    }
</script>
```

It is up to you to figure out how to chain all the inputs together

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that you'll call on click  in that you can use

`if (document.getElementById('a1_1_0').checked) {
  value = document.getElementById('a1_1_0').value;
}`

And so on for all the Radiobuttons

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the value of the checked radio buttons

The trick is to get it like this:

```
$("input[name='a1_1']:checked").val();
```

[Code example](https://jsfiddle.net/3tgz22tx/)

Afterwards you can do whatever you want with the values.

I hope this helps you.